# Autofac: resolve generic interface with optional parameters, using factory delegates

Tags: autofac

I'm trying to do the following with Autofac:

I have a class UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
  {
  IContext contextA { get; set ;}
  IContext contextB { get; set ;}

  public UnitOfWork(IContext contextA, IContext contextB)
    {
    this.contextA = contextA;
    this.contextB = contextB;
    }

  public void Save()
    {
    this.contextA.Save();
    this.contextB.Save();
    }

  ...
  }
```

I also have a generic class GenericRepo:

```
public class GenericRepo<T> : IRepo<T>
  {
  private IContext context;

  public GenericRepo(IContext context)
    {
    this.context = context;
    }
  }
```

Not typing the interfaces out, but they're there.

Then I have these delegates:

```
public delegate IUnitOfWork IUnitOfWorkFactory();

public delegate IRepo<T> IRepoFactory<T>(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = null);
```

Now the problem is this:

I need to be able to create repositories. Depending on the type of the generic repository, it has to use a different context. I don't want the calling code to have to know what context the repo is using, so I can't use the context as a parameter, it has to be the UnitOfWork.

But because the generic repo is generic, it doesn't know what context to get from a UnitOfWork, so it has to get the context through its constructor, not a UnitOfWork.

Additionally, sometimes the calling code doesn't care about the UnitOfWork (because it doesn't have to save), and in that case the UnitOfWork has to be created on the fly - it still needs one to get its data from.

So I need this to work:

```
public void TestCode(IRepoFactory<TypeA> repoFacA, IRepoFactory<TypeB> repoFacB, IUnitOfWorkFactory uowFactory)
  {
  IRepo<TypeA> repoA = repoFacA(); //repoA has contextA from a new UnitOfWork
  IRepo<TypeB> repoB = repoFacB(); //repoB has contextB from a new (different) UnitOfWork

  IUnitOfWork uow = uowFactory();
  IRepo<TypeA> repoA_2 = repoFacA(uow); //repoA_2 has contextA from uow
  IRepo<TypeB> repoB_2 = repoFacB(uow); //repoB_2 has contextB from uow
  }
```

In other words, I need to be able to call a generic delegate with a parameter, and depending on the type, it needs to construct a class using a property from that parameter.

It also needs to work without the parameter, and in that case Autofac has to resolve and use the parameter itself.

Any ideas on how to register all this in AutoFac?

Comment: Have you considered using keys http://goo.gl/aT80h or Metadata http://goo.gl/1RU06 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found it myself.

This is how I register the delegates:

```
      builder.Register((b, p) => new GenericRepo<TypeA>(((((p.First() as ConstantParameter)).Value as UnitOfWork) ?? b.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>()).ContextA)).As<IRepo<TypeA>>();
      builder.Register((b, p) => new GenericRepo<TypeB>(((((p.First() as ConstantParameter)).Value as UnitOfWork) ?? b.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>()).ContextB)).As<IRepo<TypeB>>();
```

Edit:

Or better, do it in a generic way for the first one:

```
  builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericRepository<,>)).WithParameter((pi, icc) => true, (pi, icc) => (((((icc as IInstanceLookup).Parameters.First()) as ConstantParameter).Value as IUnitOfWork) ?? icc.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>()).ContextA).As(typeof(IEntityRepository<,>));
```

The first parameter for 'WithParameter()' has to be there, and it has to return true. I guess if I wanted to filter on what parameters were given, I'd have to do it there.

Anyway. This makes it possible to, if you have a lot of types that need ContextA, and only some that need contextB, to make the generic registration for A, and then add the exceptions for B afterwards.

Suggestions on how to make this more clean or easier on the eyes are always welcome :-)